# C# Logic issue when adding fields

Tags: c#

I have a List that has 4 records. If there are animals with the same age, I need to add their ages and add it as a separate column. For example Look at the table below.

> Name | Age | Gender
>
> Ant | 9 | M
>
> Ant | 2 | M
>
> Lion| 8 | M
>
> PIG | 1 | F

There are 2 records that are duplicates (Ant). I need to add the age of the duplicates so, there'll be a new record like:

> Ant | 11 | M

All together there should be 5 records with the newly added row (added above).

The problem I am facing is, I am able to add the newly added record (which is by adding the Age fields). However, this record overrides the first record in the initial field. How can I add this record as a new field.

My code so far:

```
foreach (var animal in duplicates)
{
        Animal ani = listAnimals.First(a=> a.Name.Equals(animal.Name));

        ani.Age += animal.Age;
}
```

Comment: `listAnimals.Add(new Animal { /.../ })` ?

Comment: What happens if they don't have the same gender?

Comment: @SamW That's fine. It should be the same name Only

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using Linq easily

Assuming your Animal Type is declared as

```
public class Animal
{
public string Name {get;set;}
public int Age{get;set;}
public string Gender {get;set;}
}
```

You could Group the duplicate by Name and calculate the sum of ages.

```
var list = new List<Animal>{ 
    new Animal{Name="Ant",Age=9,Gender="M"},
    new Animal{Name="Ant",Age=2,Gender="M"},
    new Animal{Name="Lion",Age=8,Gender="M"},
    new Animal{Name="Pig",Age=1,Gender="F"},
    };

    list.AddRange( list.GroupBy(x=>x.Name)
                .Where(x=>x.Count()>1)
                .Select(x=> new Animal{Name = x.First().Name, Gender= x.First().Gender, Age = x.Sum(c=>c.Age)}));
```

Output

```
Name Age Gender
Ant   9   M 
Ant   2   M 
Lion  8   M 
Pig   1   F 
Ant   11  M
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var animals = new List<Animal>
{
    new Animal { Name = "Ant", Age = 9, Gender = "M"},
    new Animal { Name = "Ant", Age = 2, Gender = "M"},
    new Animal { Name = "Lion", Age = 8, Gender = "M"},
    new Animal { Name = "PIG", Age = 1, Gender = "F"},
};

var new_animals =
    from animal in animals
    group animal by animal.Name into grp
    where grp.Count() >= 2
    select new Animal
    {
        Name = grp.Key,
        Age = grp.Sum(a => a.Age),
        Gender = "M"
    };


animals.AddRange(new_animals);

foreach(var animal in animals)
{
    WriteLine(animal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code overwrites existing animals, because you are not creating new animals for the totals with `new Animal()`.

Getting the duplicate totals at the right place below the duplicates is quite tricky. For this I would create a new class deriving from `Animal` to be able to differentiate animals from totals records.

```
class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}

class AnimalTotals : Animal
{
}
```

Create duplicate totals like this:

```
var duplicateTotals = listAnimals
    .GroupBy(a => (a.Name, a.Gender))
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => new AnimalTotals {
        Name = g.Key.Name,
        Age = g.Sum(a => a.Age),
        Gender = g.Key.Gender
    });
```

Note that I am using value tuples (introduced in C# 7.0) to create group keys composed of a name and a gender.

Then I merge the duplicate totals with the existing list and sort the result to get the totals below the duplicates.

```
listAnimals = listAnimals
    .Concat(duplicateTotals)
    .OrderBy(a => a.Name)
    .ThenBy(a => a.Gender)
    .ThenBy(a => a is AnimalTotals ? 1 : 0)
    .ToList();
```

With this sample data

```
var listAnimals = new List<Animal> {
    new Animal{ Name="Ant",  Age = 9, Gender = "M" },
    new Animal{ Name="Ant",  Age = 2, Gender = "M" },
    new Animal{ Name="Ant",  Age = 5, Gender = "F" },
    new Animal{ Name="Ant",  Age = 1, Gender = "F" },
    new Animal{ Name="Lion", Age = 8, Gender = "M" },
    new Animal{ Name="Pig",  Age = 1, Gender = "F" },
};
```

The output of

```
foreach (Animal a in listAnimals) {
    if (a is AnimalTotals) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{a.Name} {a.Gender} totals: {a.Age,4}");
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine($"{a.Name,-6}   {a.Age,2}   {a.Gender}");
    }
}
```

is

```
Ant       5   F
Ant       1   F
Ant F totals:    6
Ant       9   M
Ant       2   M
Ant M totals:   11
Lion      8   M
Pig       1   F
```